# getting a java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException from an array.get?

Tags: android

Ok I have an sqlite database that is collecting data from the user- this is information is then sent to a string array and displayed on screen with the following code-

The Array itself and its int

```
List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

int currentPos = 0;
```

here's the next button

```
nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentPos++;
                if (currentPos > array.size()) {
                    currentPos = 0;
                }
                textView.setText(array.get(currentPos));
            }
        });
```

here's the previous button

```
prevBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentPos --;
                if (currentPos < 0) {
                    currentPos = array.size();
                }
                textView.setText(array.get(currentPos));
            }
        });
```

heres log cat with the error

```
12-10 16:08:31.867 16630-16630/com.package.www.randomApp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.package.www.randomApp, PID: 16630
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 8, size is 8
    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
    at com.package.www.randomApp.FavoritesMenu$2.onClick(FavoritesMenu.java:66)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4654)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19438)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the error is pointing at the following code line

```
textView.setText(array.get(currentPos));
```

The error pops up with both buttons.

I know this error means that the position being called in the array doesn't exist this is probably me doing my math wrong but I can't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                currentPos++;
                if (currentPos> array.size() - 1) currentPos= 0;
                textView.setText(array.get(currentPos));


            }
        });

prevBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                currentPos --;
                if (currentPos < 0) currentPos = array.size() - 1;
                textView.setText(array.get(currentPos ));
            }
        });
```

Comment: because the arraylist has length 8, but your variable starts from 0. the list's firtst index item is 0 and the last 7

Comment: @ParagonTime did you understand or you want to make you an example?

Answer (score 1):

```
currentPos++;
if (currentPos> array.size()) currentPos= 0;
```

7 becomes 8. 8 is not greater than 8. So currentPos does not become 0.

Fixed by: `if (currentPos>= array.size()) currentPos= 0;`

Or: `if (currentPos> array.size() - 1) currentPos= 0;`